# choose rescue grub in change root environment

Tags: grub, rescue

I have an online root server which only gives kernel panic since last update.

Now I would like to change grub settings to start in rescue mode. I `chroot`-ed into the system from my rescue console:

```
M=/mnt/root
mkdir -p $M
mount /dev/md127 $M
mount -t proc none $M/proc
mount -o bind /dev $M/dev
mount -t sysfs sys $M/sys
mount --bind /dev/pts $M/dev/pts
chroot $M/ /bin/bash
```

And I think the right way is to edit the grub config at

```
/etc/default/grub
```

and enable it with

```
update-grub
```

But How do I find out which `GRUB_DEFAULT` I have to choose?

The output of `update-grub` is:

```
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-686-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-4-686-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-686-bigmem
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-5-686-bigmem
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of update-grub already shows the order off grub options starting with zero.

So in this case the default 2 will start the 2.6 kernel